# dojox.mobile.view slow

Tags: dojo

when tapping just on the "Back button" it last 1-1.5secs (iOS 4-5 iPhones) seconds before it goes back. Is there anything I can do ?

I had a closer look and removed ALL bottlenecks in my code. Even when the view is empty, its unacceptable slow.

I also had a look in the dojo sources, its seems that dojo.setStyle and dojo.setClass is called a few hundreds times when moving in or out a view. I debugged this with a self baken mozilla browser and its true, dojo view changes involve a complete repaint/reflow of the entire dom tree, thats more than bad.

We spent now 3.5 months fulltime on a commercial project and the customer is not happy with the performance at all and I'am facing a little desaster.

I also saw that dojo prefers DOM manipulation instead of innerHTML and wants even stick to that. Are there any workarounds or utils within the DOJO framework to support innerHTML approaches ?

Looks, I need to rewrite the view class.

Any suggestions are welcome, guenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running an optimized build or from source? Any chance this is a file load/latency problem?

I'd recommend you take your comments to [dojo-interest](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/mailman/listinfo/dojo-interest) where the community and dojox.mobile maintainers are more likely to see it.  You may also want to post some examples to demonstrate the performance problems you're seeing.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response. No, its not a latency problem. Even then i reuse my views its same slow as before. I tried the shrinksafe and the closure compiler but it doesnt have any impact except loading speed. I tried the dojo-interest but stil no answer. you can see byself the problem here : www.bitly.com/imtablet2. Guenter.

Comment: it looks like you posted with nabble and you're not subscribed to the list?  I'll pass your message along.